# My while loop is not working for some reason

Tags: python

```
import random
n = 1
tala = random.randrange(0,11)
print('talan er ' + str(tala))

print('The goal is to guess the number.')
num = input('Pick a number: ')

while num != tala:
    if num < tala:
        print('Too Low')
        num = input('Try again: ')
    elif num > tala:
        print('Too High')
        num = input('Try again: ')
    else:
        print('wow congratulations, you guessed the right number in ' + str(n) + ' tries.')
    n += 1
```

Above is my code, and below is the error that I am encountering.

I can't seem to find my error which is: It's just a simple code, but the error is something I can't find.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ebben/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/GuessNumber.py", line 10, in <module>
    if num < tala:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python input is always string and you need to convert it to integer by adding `int()` method

here is your code:
you need to change `num`:

```
import random
n = 1
tala = random.randrange(0,11)
print('talan er ' + str(tala))

print('The goal is to guess the number.')
num = int(input('Pick a number: '))

while num != tala:
    if num < tala:
        print('Too Low')
        num = int(input('Try again: '))
    elif num > tala:
        print('Too High')
        num = int(input('Try again: '))
    else:
        print('wow congratulations, you guessed the right number in ' + str(n) + ' tries.')
    n += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error show that less than `<` operator and `>` operator must be compared with `number` data type which either `int` or `float`. which mean variable `num` is a `string` object.

So replace the following line to solved your error:-

Replace

```
 if num < tala:
```

into

```
 if int(num) < tala:
```

### &

Replace

```
 if num > tala:
```

into

```
 if int(num) > tala:
```